# Export data from advertising platforms (FB Ads, Google Ads, My Target) into Prometheus to visualize in Grafana

Tags: python, database, export, prometheus, grafana

We are marketing agency that wants all the ads campaign data (Facebook Ads, Google Ads, My Target) to be displayed in the dashboard(Grafana + Prometheus). We were looking for plugins that can extract the data to Prometheus, and then get visualized in Grafana. Did anyone find any plugins/exporters/ or any solution that will work with minimum coding?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such plugin/exporter. Since this kinds of platforms are correcting the results for like two weeks prior.

The best way to visualize this kind of information in Grafana is to use a good persistency layer and store data in a database like Postgres or MySQL.

So you need to write your own ETL processes or use third-party services.